# How to return output parameter from sql in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all I am having an output parameter defined in my stored procedure, my sp is as follows

```
createproc [dbo].[convertempID](@empid int,@totcnt varchar(4) output)
as
begin
    select @totcnt = right('00000'+convert(varchar(6), empID), 4)
        from tblEmployee
        where empID = @empid;
end
```

When I execute this I am getting result as `0015` for `@totcnt` but when I called this in my c# code I am getting `15` instead of `0015` can some one tell where I went wrong

```
cmd.CommandText = "convertempID";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", 15);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@totcnt", SqlDbType.Int));
cmd.Parameters["@totcnt"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sring ans = cmd.Parameters["@totcnt"].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess it might be because you have selected SqlDbType.Int. If this is parsed as an int, it will be a number, and an int cannot have leading 0's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@totcnt", SqlDbType.Int));
```

Compare that with the declaration in the stored procedure:

```
@totcnt varchar(4) output
```

Change the parameter type to `SqlDbType.VarChar` and it should work. At the moment the value will actually the *integer* 15 rather than the string "0015".

Comment: No chars enough to write "I fold".

Answer (score 1):

You have specified parameter type as `Int` and there is no difference between `0015` and `15` for `Int`. Change your parameter line to:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@totcnt", SqlDbType.VarChar));
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value type has to match the type :

try to replace

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@totcnt", SqlDbType.Int));
```

with

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@totcnt", SqlDbType.VarChar));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the totcnt type from int to varchar